# Nextcloud doesn't recognize reverse proxy so brute force protection slows down connecting

Tags: docker, nginx, nextcloud

I have a nextcloud docker container behind a nginx reverse proxy also in docker.
Everything works fine except the recognition of the reverse proxy. When I typ in the wrong log in information nextcloud adds an oc_bruteforce_attempt but not with the ip of my pc but with the local docker ip of the reverse proxy. This leads to a very slow connecting and I also want my nextcloud set up properly.

My nginx conf locks like this:

```
upstream nextcloud {
  server        nextcloud:80;
}

server {
  listen        443 ssl;
  server_name   nextcloud.example.com;
  
  ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificatekey;
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://nextcloud;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    client_max_body_size 0;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    
    ##access_log /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.access.log;
    ##error_log /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.error.log;
  }

  location = /.well-known/carddav {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
  }

  location = /.well-known/caldav {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
  }
}

server {
    listen  80;

    server_name nextcloud.example.com;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

(I changed details like domain and certificates for security reasons)

And my nextcloud config.php looks like:

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'memcache.local' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu',
  'apps_paths' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/apps',
      'url' => '/apps',
      'writable' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/custom_apps',
      'url' => '/custom_apps',
      'writable' => true,
    ),
  ),
  'instanceid' => 'CHANGED',
  'passwordsalt' => 'CHANGED',
  'secret' => 'CHANGED',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'nextcloud',
    1 => 'nextcloud.example.com',
    2 => 'localhost',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/data',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '26.0.0.11',
  'dbname' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbhost' => 'nextcloud-mariadb',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'CHANGED',
  'dbpassword' => 'CHANGED',
  'installed' => true,
  'trusted_proxies' => array('reverse-proxy', '172.20.0.3'),
  'overwriteprotocol' => 'https',
  'overwritehost' => 'nextcloud.example.com',
  'overwritecondaddr' => '172\.20\.0\.3',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://nextcloud.example.com/',
  'forwarded_for_headers' => array('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'),
);
```

I also don't really know how to put the container name instead of the ip into the config.php in this lines:

```
'trusted_proxies' => array('reverse-proxy', '172.20.0.3'),
'overwritecondaddr' => '172\.20\.0\.3',
```

Thanks for help in advance!

I've tried to change small differences like
array('reverse-proxy', '172.20.0.3') => ['reverse-proxy', '172.20.0.3']
but it didn't work out.